# Ternary operatory for the stament

Tags: if-statement, ternary-operator

```
if( $a == $b) { return true;} 
else { return false;}
```

how to write a ternary operater for the following ?

is this the way

```
if($a == $b)? return true; : return false;
```

Comment: yes.....................

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need the ternary operator at all. Just return this and you'll get the correct `true` or `false` value.

```
return $a == $b;
```

Answer (score 4):

You could just

```
return ($a == $b)
```

But if you really want to use the operator

```
return ( ($a == $b) ? true : false)
```

Comment: incase instead of return true i wanna return a variable... can i do this

return ( ($a == $b) ? $variable : false)

Comment: yes, in  C ? A : B both A and B can be arbitrary expressions, you could have a single variable as you suggest, or even complex sums. Your idea of using a varibale makes for readable code.